# Can a set of $2\times 2$ matrices form a group if the main diagonal equals $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I'm asked to prove the set of all matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a+d=0$ is a group with respect to matrix addition.

I don't think this is possible since you cannot get the identity/neutral element given the condition that $a+d=0$.

Comment: What is the identity for addition?

Comment: If you know about group homomorphisms, then the set in question is the kernel of the trace map.

Answer (score 3):

Call the set of such matrices $S$.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix} s & t\\ u & v\end{pmatrix}$ be in $S$. Then $a+d=s+v=0$. Now

$$A+B=\begin{pmatrix} a+s & b+t \\ c+u & d+v\end{pmatrix}$$

is in $S$, too, since

$$\begin{align}
(a+s)+(d+v)&=(a+d)+(s+v)\\
&=0+0\\
&=0.\end{align}$$ Hence $(S,+)$ is closed.

Associativity follows from standard associativity of matrices under matrix addition, which itself follows from associativity of elements of $\Bbb R$ under $+$.

The identity is

$$0=\begin{pmatrix} \color{red}{0} & 0\\ 0 & \color{blue}{0}\end{pmatrix}$$

since, indeed, $\color{red}{0}+\color{blue}{0}=0$ and

$$A+0=0+A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}.$$

The inverse of $A$ is clearly $-A=\begin{pmatrix} -a & -b\\ -c & -d\end{pmatrix}$, which is in $S$ because $(-a)+(-d)=-(a+d)=-0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The neutral element in this case is the zero matrix which satisfies $a+d=0$.

Hence, it is possible.

Additional exercise after you solve this particular problem:

- Try to prove that that set of matrices of size $n$ where the trace is $0$ is a group with respect to matrix addition.